# Pipe username and other parameters to command-line utility

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sh

Having some command-line utility that asks for input several times when you launch it, e.g. here I need to pass username and host to some command.
And I would like to make other command so it will pass these args

```
user:~$ run_something
username:
host:
```

How it is possible to pipe these parameters sequentially to command, e.g.:

```
user:~$ echo "my_user, my_host" | run_something
```

Comment: Use `read -r username host` inside `run_something` and use it as: `echo "my_user my_host" | run_something`

Answer (score 0):

use xargs

eg.

```
echo "mydir" | xargs ls
```

Will list the files in the directory mydir

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using `read` from standard input:

```
run_something() {
   read -r username host && declare -p username host;
}
```

then run it as:

```
echo "my_user my_host" | run_something
```

to get output:

```
declare -- username="my_user"
declare -- host="my_host"
```

Another way is to set variables directly before calling function:

```
run_something() {
   declare -p username host
}
```

then run it as:

```
username='my_user' host='my_host' run_something
```

to get the same output:

```
declare -x username="my_user"
declare -x host="my_host"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the newlines that you would otherwise type after each line. `run_something` is expecting two lines of input:

```
printf '%s\n' "username" "host" | run_something
```